# Is Primefaces able to get jquery from another domain?

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces for some of my pages in my JSF2 app.  I would like to control where the page gets the jquery.js from. Is there a way to specify in the faces-config or web.xml to not add the JQuery javascript libraries.

For example don't add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myappcontextroot/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces"></script>
```

I would prefer the page output something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

Or not do output anything when needed the jquery library.  (I will manually add the above to the page.)

Is this even possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You basically need a custom [resource handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html?is-external=true) which returns the desired external URL on `Resource#getRequestPath()` whenever the resource `primefaces:jquery/jquery.js` is been requested.

E.g.

```
public class CDNResourceHandler extends ResourceHandlerWrapper {

    private ResourceHandler wrapped;

    public CDNResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource createResource(final String resourceName, final String libraryName) {
        final Resource resource = super.createResource(resourceName, libraryName);

        if (resource == null || !"primefaces".equals(libraryName) || !"jquery/jquery.js".equals(resourceName)) {
            return resource;
        }

        return new ResourceWrapper() {

            @Override
            public String getRequestPath() {
                return "http://mydomain.com/jquery/jquery.js";
            }

            @Override
            public Resource getWrapped() {
                return resource;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

To get it to run, map it in `faces-config.xml` as follows:

```
<application>
    <resource-handler>com.example.CDNResourceHandler</resource-handler>
</application>
```

The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) offers a reusable solution in flavor of [`CDNResourceHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler) which is in your case to be configured as

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>primefaces:jquery/jquery.js=http://mydomain.com/jquery/jquery.js</param-value>
</context-param>
```